# Keras Data augmentation for semantic segmentation producing black output

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, computer-vision

I'm trying to perform data augmentation on both image and mask using keras. My input mask is black/white but output is completely black and I'm not sure what part is wrong.

1. If my mask is black and white is it correct to use cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE?
2. What would cause this black mask?  please click link I can't upload image directly.

Input image:

[image: input image]

Output image:

[image: Output image]

```
    img_augmented_path = PATH+'\\new_data\images'
    mask_augmented_path = PATH+'\\new_data\masks'
    
    aug = A.Compose([
        A.VerticalFlip(p=0.5),
        A.HorizontalFlip(p=0.5),
    ])
    
    i = 1
    
    random.seed = 42
    while i < 5:
        number = random.randint(0, len(imageset)-1)
        image = imageset[number]
        mask = maskset[number]
    
        print(image,mask)
        org_image = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(image), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        org_mask = cv2.imread(mask, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    
        agumented = aug(image=org_image, mask=org_mask)
        transformed_image = augmented['image']
        transformed_mask = augmented['mask']
    
        new_image_path = '%s\\augemented_image_%s.png'%(img_augmented_path,i)
        new_mask_path = '%s\\augemented_mask_%s.png'%(mask_augmented_path,i)
        io.imsave(new_image_path,transformed_image)
        io.imsave(new_mask_path,transformed_mask)
        i = i+1


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2ifu.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MXBo.png
```

Comment: Check for the data type of `org_mask` after reading the mask. Make sure it is of `int` type and not `float`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I did check the data type and actually, it was ndarray and unit8. Somehow I played around and changed the order of 'mask' and 'image' like <  agumented = aug(mask=org_mask, image = org_image)> and it worked. I'm not sure why the order of variable matters...